# Does .htaccess file size matter?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to know does the file size of `.htaccess` matter? I read somewhere that a large `.htaccess` file can slow down website performance.

My `.htaccess` file size is `51KB` and it contains around `500 lines` which are mostly `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}` rules to block spam referrer websites.

But I didn't notice any website loading lag or performance issue.

If I convert those 500 `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}` lines into 20 lines, each containing 25 spam referrer domain names in groups using `()` and `|` symbols, will it change anything?

For example convert following lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} hol\.es [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} hys\.cz [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} zzz\.com\.ua [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} hypersito\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} tode\.cz [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} mzf\.cz [NC,OR]
```

into following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (hol\.es|hys\.cz|zzz\.com\.ua|hypersito\.com|tode\.cz|mzf\.cz) [NC,OR]
```

Will it reduce CPU load and cause less CPU cycles? Or will it remain same as having 500 separate lines?

Comment: _Aside:_ What are you trying to achieve by blocking these "spam" referers? Are they currently causing a problem?

Comment: Yes. Many linkbacks are coming from these spam referrers which actually don't contain any real link to my website. All links are coming from low-traffic websites such as porn, medical, pizza, burger, shopping websites, etc. My GWT "Links to your sites" section is full with these spam links. So I'm blocking these spam referrers. I'm regularly checking GWT and Awstat and whenever I find any new spam referrer, I'm adding it to .htaccess block list.

Comment: But is this actually a "real problem"? Is it causing a degradation in site performance or consuming all your bandwidth? Otherwise, "blocking" the request is not really going to help. The link will still exist and GSC (formerly GWT) will still report it (although you say there is no "real link"). If in-bound links are actually resulting in an SEO _penalty_ then you can use [Google's Disavow link tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en).

Comment: "Referer spam" is an unfortunate reality, trying to manually keep up with it is generally a fruitless task and is not without its dangers. Referer spam is usually "only" a reporting problem - if this is a metric that you monitor. And as such is something that would generally only need to be filtered out when reporting - when performance is not usually so critical.

Comment: Last month Google Adsense deducted 60% from my total earning due to invalid traffic/activity and I'm sure it was happened due to these spam referrer links. That's why I'm blocking these spam domains using .htaccess. If I do nothing about these referrer links, I'm afraid Adsense will again deduct huge amount due to invalid traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With so many rules, you really should take the [advice from the Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html) to heart

> You should avoid using `.htaccess` files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using `.htaccess` files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a `.htaccess` file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.

`.htaccess` files have two major performance impact points:

- The directory tree must be scanned for them. Just turning them off avoids this overhead.
- Every rule in a `.htaccess` file needs to be evaluated for every single request, while putting those rules in the regular config file means they get evaluated once, upon the start of Apache (or reload).

So, you are much better off to put those rules into your main config file.

> But I didn't notice any website loading lag or performance issue.

Of course, these performance considerations are only relevant if you get a higher workload. For a mostly idle server, this isn't very relevant, but if the load gets high, this will start to have a real impact.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you tell me how to put these rules into https main server config file? And what will be the syntax of using directory to block these spam referrer domains?

Comment: This should be another question. But search the web, you will find plenty of guides about this (and many questions on [SF]).

Comment: Thanks and what about my other question? If I combine multiple `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}` lines into one using | symbol, will it change anything? Will it reduce CPU load, etc? Or there is no difference between having separate lines of rules and having combined rules.

Comment: This is really hard to say. My guess would be that in a `.htaccess` file, it makes matters a little bit worse as evaluating these combined statements is actually  more difficult. In the config file, I guess it wouldn't matter as much or at all as the rules get evaluated only once anyway. But I would consider that the easier maintenance of "one rule per line" always is more important than the small performance difference you may or may not have, regardless of `.htaccess` or config file.